# How to apply GPO on Local station?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have created in the past some rules manaed by the console on the active directory.

I would like to apply the GPO managed by the AD, on a standalone station not connected to the AD.

how can I convert use the exported GPO and to apply it on the Local policies?

Comment: Which GPO rule ?

Comment: Generally, you just apply the preferred setting on the workstation, or you can export the specific registry keys (if that is where the setting is stored) and import it to accomplish the same thing. So, to do this, you're going to have to specify the setting (the GPO rule).